# Covering Index Not Being Used Effectively

Tags: mysql, performance, index, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a unique composite index on three fields (hash, is_customer, user_id) in a table a.

And queries that go like this:

```
select `a`.`id`, `hash`, `is_customer`, `user_id` 
from `a` 
where `hash` = 34605915 
limit 1;
```

When I do explain, it identifies properly as:

```
Using where; Using index |
```

However the above query showed up in a slow query log as `Full_scan: Yes` and query time of over 5.083821 seconds.

The dump of the explain is as follows:

```
| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "a",
      "access_type": "index",
      "possible_keys": ["a_hash_unique"],
      "key": "a_id_hash_is_customer_user_id_unique",
      "key_length": "138",
      "used_key_parts": ["id", "hash", "is_customer", "user_id"],
      "rows": 2639299,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "db.a.hash = 34605915",
      "using_index": true
    }
  }
} |
```

The InnoDB pool buffer pool size is set to 21G (actual pool data size is about 18.1G) and pool instances as 21. What could be the explanation for the optimized missing this query index? In the process, I think the same issue causes the system to run into deadlocks during DB writes.

Below is the table structure dump:

```
 a | CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `anum` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `currency` char(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NGN',
  `hash` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=Current, 2=Savings, 3=Fixed, 4=Overdraft, 5=Loan, 6=Joint, 7=Other',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_customer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a_hash_unique` (`hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a_id_hash_is_customer_user_id_unique` (`id`,`hash`,`is_customer`,`user_id`),
  KEY `a_bid_index` (`bid`),
  KEY `a_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `a_bid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`bid`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `a_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6004761 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: Show full table's DDL. Add ORDER BY - LIMIT without it makes no sense. Tell how many rows there is in a table totally and what percent of them is selected without LIMIT.

Comment: I think ""access_type": "index"" also says that the index is "covering".  WAIT!  What's `id` doing at the start of the index??  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

`Using index` means that an index was "covering" and was used.  Or, at least, when the `EXPLAIN` was run, it decided that.

I have looked at thousands of `EXPLAINs` and slowlog entries.  In theory, they always match.  However, there is nothing that forces the `EXPLAIN` to actually match what happens and is recorded in the slowlog.

I have seen as many as 6 different `EXPLAINs` for a given query "digest".  But that is easily explained by different cardinality, etc.

Could you provide the full, exact, text of the `EXPLAIN` and the slowlog entry.  I would like to see if I can spot something.  Also, if available, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Actually, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would probably have the clue.

```
WHERE `hash` = 34605915
```

If `hash` is `VARCHAR`, then this cannot use the index.  Add quotes to the *string* "34605915".

Or, if `hash` is always numeric, then make it an integer datatype, perhaps `INT UNSIGNED` (32-bit number; 4-bytes).

When mixing char and int, MySQL will convert the varchar to int before comparing.  So, the one case of "varchar_col = integer-constant" cannot use the index effectively.

Comment: Wow, hash is indeed a varchar, does it mean I need to quote hash as string in the query to use the index?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - Yes, else it is obligated to convert each varchar to a number before testing.  Alternatively, if the has is really just a number, change it to `INT UNSIGNED` or some other suitable integer datatype.  _Then_ the index will be very efficiently used.

Comment: OK but even so, does this mean there will be a full table scan?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - No.  It will go directly to the desired row(s).